# Fourier coefficients - can I see them?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification, fourier-series, orthonormal

> Let $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n$ be an orthonormal basis for the $n$-dimensional vector space $\mathcal V$. Let $x\in \mathcal V$ have the representation $x=\sum b_i v_i$. Show that the Fourier coefficients $b_i$ can be computed as $b_i=\langle x, v_i\rangle$.

If I take the inner product of both sides I get $$\begin{split}\langle x, v_i\rangle&=\langle \sum_{j=1}^n b_j v_j, v_i\rangle\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j\langle v_j, v_i\rangle\\
&=b_i\|v_i\|^2\\
&=b_i\end{split}$$

Is the point of this that $x$ might not be written in the form $\sum b_iv_i$ explicitly (i.e. you can't actually see the $b_i$'s) and so you can find the $b_i$'s by taking the inner product w.r.t. each orthonormal basis vector? What I'm trying to say is that the way it's written, I can see the $b_i$'s. Am I supposed to assume that I don't know them or is it actually about *you can see the $b_i$'s* and you can *also get them by doing the inner product*. (Or both?)

Comment: The existence of such a representation follows (by definition) from the set being a basis for the vectorspace.

Comment: Yes, as you say, the assertion/assumption/fact that the $v_i$'s are a basis only says that for every $x$ there _exist_ coefficients to express $x$ as a linear combination. That definition does not ahead-of-time require those coefficients to be given in any convenient or visible way. The additional assumption of orthonormality of the basis assures that your computation does correctly _determine_ the coefficients (which we somehow already knew _existed_). It is sometimes possible to fallaciously "solve for" a thing whose existence is problemmatic, but here that's not the case. :)

Comment: It's both. As with many other mathematical identities, it's useful in different ways in different contexts. Sometimes it's a handy way to rewrite stuff when doing theoretical work. Other times it's a good way to actually compute the $b_i$'s.

Comment: FYI this even works for infinite dimensional Hilbert spaces (Though not all vector spaces are Hilbert spaces).  This is called a "Hilbert basis",  to differentiate it from the Hamel basis, which is what you first learn. (Though on finite dimensional vector spaces, Hamel bases and Hilbert Bases both have $n$ elements,  in infinite dimensions the cardinalities can differ)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such linear combination always exists, no matter whether you can see it immediately or not. Since it exists, it makes sense for us to write this expression.

And yes, you are correct that the coordinate $b_i$'s can be found by taking the inner product between $x$ and the basis element $v_i$'s though we may not know it before.